# What is a "universal algebraic curve of genus 1"?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I need to understand how exactly the construction of the universal algebraic curve (in this [sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_bundle)) goes in the context of elliptic curves over the complex numbers.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can do at least part of the conceptual exercise to imagine that the coefficients of an elliptic curve (e.g., in Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$) are themselves "transcendental", or, "variously", that they are in an affine parametrizing space, etc.

Comment: There are two approaches to this: analytical and algebro-geometric. How much Teichmuller theory or theory of moduli do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your question for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. Note however that your link refers to $\mathcal{M}_1$, the moduli space of curves of genus $1$ (rather than elliptic curves, which need a marked point) - since automorphism groups of genus $1$ curves are infinite your question would become rather more subtle.

Anyway, for elliptic curves. First recall that elliptic curves $E$ and $F$ defined over an algebraically closed field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same $j$-invariant; from this it follows that $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ (or at least its $\mathbb{C}$-points, after passing to non-algebraically closed extensions one might need adjectives like "coarse space") is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_j$, we associate to each elliptic curve its $j$-invariant. Conversely for each $j \in \mathbb{C}$ we may associate the elliptic curve
$$E_j : y^2 = x^3 - 27 j(j-1728)x - 54 j(j-1728)^2$$
which has $j$-invariant $j$.

The universal elliptic curve over $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ is then not so hard to define; it is the elliptic surface
$$\mathcal{E} : y^2 = x^3 - 27j(j-1728)x - 54j(j-1728)^2$$
equipped with the obvious morphism $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$.

Comment: what does the $j$ in $\mathbb{A}_j^1$ mean?

Comment: See [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528357/the-j-line-formed-the-coarse-moduli-space-for-elliptic-curves](this)

Comment: @MattPark it's just notation, it's saying that the coordinate on the line is $j$, if say you transformed $j$ by a Mobius map you'd get $\mathbb{A}^1$, but the moduli interpretation would be skew-whiff